# expectation of number of exactly 3 heads flip in a row

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

lets say I have 400 coin tosses and a probability P for head.

$\{ x_n \}$ the tosses,then X is a random variable which X = {number of times which there where exactly 3 heads}

how can I calculate E[x] and Var[x]?

I tried to get to the solution through recursion by choose where the first 3 exactly heads will be but with no luck.
k=400 ,
P(X=n) = F(n,k) = F(n-1,k-4)+F(n-1,k-5)+F(n-1,k-6)+F(n-1,k-7)

Comment: Hint (for expected value at least):  use Linearity of Expectation, and for $i\in \{1,398\}$ let $X_i$ be the indicator variable which tells you if a string of exactly three Heads starts with the $i^{th}$ toss.

Comment: but $X \neq \sum_i X_i$

Comment: Not following.  Why do you think they aren't equal? The number of exact  triples  $HHH$ equals the number of places where exact triples start.  Note:  Variance can be done this way but it is more work.  For each pair $i,j$ you have to analyze $E[X_iX_j]$.

Comment: Ok Now I get it, thanks!